# Visual Studio - navigate to a method by its fully qualified name

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

In Visual Studio, **if we haven't already found a method reference**, can the IDE find and go directly to the definition of a method by fully qualified name. E.g:

```
Orchard.Core.Contents.Controllers.ItemController.Display
```

... without going to other methods named Display or other classes named ItemController.

Ideally, it would be a search box that takes the fully qualified method name.

The following do NOT work:

1. *Find* for text and would require serious regex.
2. *Go to* for line numbers.
3. *Navigate to* not sure yet.
4. *Go to definition* only if you have a reference to the method.

**Class View Works** works, though it *sometimes doesn't* if the solution is configured in certain ways:

[image: Class View doesn't find the method by fully qualified name.]

Comment: "to go" means what? Like with the browser url? or point the IDE to show you the code for that method?

Comment: Point the IDE to show me the code for that method.

Comment: Right-click on `Index` and choose *Go To Definition* works unless you're dealing with an Interface.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to navigate to the method directly without having the current method present in the code, you can use the [Class View](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sy6s2t6h%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) pane and type in the full method name in the search box.

Additionally, if the method is present in the code, you can right click on the method and select `Go to definition` or just put the text cursor on the method name and hit `F12`.

Some additional features to check out:

- [Find all references](http://www.blackwasp.co.uk/VSFindAllReferences.aspx)
- [Peek definition](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn160178.aspx)

Comment: What if don't have that method to click. I.e. someone tells me to add a break point to `MvcMusicsStore.Controllers.StoreController.Index`. How do I go directly to it?

Comment: Maybe try out this extension: http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/4b286b9c-4dd5-416b-b143-e31d36dc622b

Comment: If you right click on it you should have options, if you are set for C# it is F12 as @dhsto said.  If you have VB settings its Shift-F2.  So you use the F12 (or Shift-F2) key if you don't want to use right click menu. If you right click you select from menu.

Comment: @ShaunLuttin also, post a screenshot of what it looks like when you right click on the method name. You mention this is C# code in the tag, so as long as that method is navigable then you will be able to navigate to the code.

Comment: @dhsto I don't have the method name to click. If I haven't even found a method reference, is there a way to find the definition?

Comment: @ShaunLuttin oh I see what you mean. You can open up the Class View and type in the full name. I've updated my answer.

Comment: @dhsto That doesn't appear to work for me either. I just tried to search, for instance, `Orchard.Core.Contents.Controllers.ItemController` within the Orchard source, and Class View did not find it.

Comment: @ShaunLuttin well if Class View doesn't work for you then I don't know what to recommend. It works perfectly for me. Is that class perhaps stored in a referenced dll?

Comment: @dhsto Thanks for the help! I appreciate it. Unfortunately, though, the class is not in a DLL. I added an image of the failed class view search in my question.

Comment: @ShaunLuttin hmmm... that's very strange. Maybe make sure everything under that gear icon (Class View settings) is checked. Other than that, I really don't know how else to help. Sorry about that.

Comment: @dhsto Gotcha. Everything is checked. It might be weirdness in the Orchard solution configuration.

Comment: @dhsto Could you please highlight the Class View aspect of your answer in **bold** to emphasize that as the answer.

Comment: @ShaunLuttin yeah maybe, but I'm not sure how. Sure, I'll update it.

Answer (score 1):

JetBrains' ReSharper has a feature to open any type/file/symbol based on (parts of) its name. It's in the Resharper menu below Navigate -> "Go to Everything /Type (Ctrl + T)"